# Android Studio: "Waiting for device." Trying to run app on phone

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I'm attempting to transition from Eclipse to Android Studio today. I generated the Gradle build files in Eclipse and imported into Android Studio. I changed my preferences to run the app from a USB device instead of the emulator. Now when I run my app with my phone plugged in, all I get is a message that says "Waiting for device."

Has anyone else tried out Android Studio and got an app running on their phone? I'd appreciate any advice. I've been trying for quite a while now.

Comment: This message shows when adb server is being started. Try `adb devices` through command line to see if adb picks up any devices.

Comment: I get `adb: command not found`

Comment: Go to `android-studio/sdk/platform-tools` where `adb` is located, then run it.

Comment: Woah I just got it. I restarted Android Tools then tried to run and got the messages `Waiting for device.` and `USB device not found`. I then unplugged my phone and replugged it in, ran again, and voila the app ran! Well thanks for your help!

Comment: check if your device is in debug mode, and allows unknown sources to run on it, also make sure it does not get recognized as "mass data storage"

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the problem as stated in my above comment.

Comment: I also got 'waiting for debugger' in Android Studio. Simply updating to the latest version (0.5.4) solved it for me.

Comment: Anyone have any more ideas? I've tried everything in these comments and answers, and still it's waiting for device. It still works fine in Eclipse. `adb devices` lists my device as online. I've rebooted the device and my PC. I've tried it with a Genymotion device. Always waiting for device. I've updated the SDK build tools to the latest, and Android Studio to the latest. Going to add a bounty...

Comment: @Tenfour04 Have you started Android studio, waited for adb, then done an unplug/replug? Usually Android studio doesn't recognize the device when you start it with your device already plugged in.

Comment: Yes, I've tried every answer on this page in every combination/order I can think of. I did try unplugging/replugging after opening Android Studio. I also rebooted the device and have tried three different devices that all work fine with Eclipse.

Comment: Which operating system you are on? Win or Linux?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I get this from time to time and a simple unplug/replug of the device does the trick.

Comment: you can also use "adb kill-server" and restart it for example via "adb devices". This does the same thing without having to touch the cable. Also the cable solution won't work with wireless adb connection.

Answer (score 16):

**If you have an LG G3**

I've seen a couple of posts about people having issues connecting their LG G3 to adb...major PITA because the solution is very non-intuitive.

Turns out you need to switch the USB mode to Send Images (PTP). You can find this menu by clicking on the notification item that says "Tap for more USB options" right after plugging your phone in.

More info: http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/guide-connecting-lg-g3-to-linux-adb-aka-t2821673

Comment: oh my god. That's 3 hours of my life I want back. How can LG possibly release such garbage!?

Answer (score 12):

I have `LG G3` connected to Android Studio and got `USB device not found`.

I fixed this problem doing the following steps:

1. Enable Developer option
2. In there, check `USB debugging` and `Allow mock locations`
3. Go into `Tethering & Networks` and put USB tethering ON. Bluetooth didn't work for me.
4. Finally, run *debug* in Android Studio

Comment: Oh I didn't even think about people not knowing to enable developer mode on their phone. I assumed if they got this far they knew they needed to do that. Probably good you posted this.

Comment: Turn on Usb tethering did it for me.

Comment: I just had Samsung galaxy 3 or something and nothing of this worked unless i turned USB tethering OFF.. Weird but worked.

Comment: In my mobile it is `Tethering & portable hotspot`

Answer (score 7):

I started getting this message after I had disabled the "Media device (MTP)" and "Camera (PTP)" option in the "USB computer connection" option found in Settings > Storage > USB computer connection. Re-enabling one of either MTP or PTP fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

this also help me some times :

```
adb kill-server 
adb start-server
```

and phone or emulator is reconnected to adb

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem and I was able fix that problem.

My error was:

> Waiting for device. USB device not found

This happens when I was using SONY XPERIA Tipo Dual and Samsung Galaxy Core Duos i8262.

I solved problem in both devices.

**SONY XPERIA Tipo Dual**

1. Check whether "USB debugging" is enable or not in Settings->Developer Options
2. Connect device to PC and run your app. Make sure "Target Device" as "USB Device" in Run/Debug Configurations.
3. If error was "Waiting for device. USB device not found", Go to "Device Manager" and check your device is categorize as "Other Devices" in yellow color. That means your device is not detected by Windows.
4. Install "[SONY PC Companion](http://www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/Software%20Downloads/PC%20Companion/Sony%20PC%20Companion_2.10.136_Web.exe)" which is automatically detect your driver.
5. Run your app again. You can see your app is running in your device.

**Samsung Galaxy Core Duos i8262**

1. Check whether "USB debugging" is enable or not in Settings->Developer Options
2. Connect device to PC and run your app. Make sure "Target Device" as "USB Device" in Run/Debug Configurations.
3. If error was "Waiting for device. USB device not found", Go to "Device Manager" and check your device is categorize as "Other Devices" in yellow color. That means your device is not detected by Windows.
4. Install USB drive. You can find it [here](http://www.samsung.com/levant/support/model/GT-I8262CWAAFR). Direct [Url](http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_LEVANT&CttFileID=5319211&CDCttType=SW&ModelType=N&ModelName=GT-I8262&VPath=SW/201410/20141017131240597/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe) to download
5. Run your app again. You can see that still you are getting same error. Go to notification section. You can see that, phone is **connected as a media device(Media device(MTP))**. You need to change it as "Camera (PTP)" by touching notification.
6. Run your app again. Wow. It works...

Answer (score 4):

Ensure Debug mode is turned on, as well as allowing installations from unknown locations, if the problem continues, unplugging the device, rebooting and plugging the device back in should work

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I am using Kubuntu and I can get the phone to recognize it, but it is gibberish in the "Device" and "Serial" columns, producing only a NULL and ?????'s. I have tried to use the emulator but even that is buggy. I got the emulator to start only to have it "lose" the phone icon, (without the persistence button checked either) and the camera icon, as well as it saying "could not access the package manager".

I restarted the program, and all was working fine. It helps to have patience.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with the RSA security authentication that happens between your PC and mobile. When you connect your mobile device with USB debugging enabled, you must be getting a popup to authorize the computer to use USB debugging on your device. Just check "Always allow" and things should work smoothly.

Actual problem is when you connect your device to your PC the first time after enabling the USB debugging, the popup for RSA authentication just disappears after a while. So all you have to do is, disconnect and reconnect the mobile device and set the authorization on popup.

Comment: Not at all the scenario I had but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it after switching to another **USB** cable.