# Connection Timeout while running app on device from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this error whenever I try to run app from android studio. I am stuck badly. Any suggestion?

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: 021eff812391377f
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Optimusprime\AndroidStudioProjects\Info2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/manojmm.info
I/O Error: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: Does the device have USB debugging enabled?

Comment: yup..  @stkent usb debugging is on. I am able to select device but then after I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Lot of things that you can do:

1. Unplug and replug the device from the USB connection.
2. Ensure that the debug mode of the phone is on.
3. Try killing and restarting the adb with `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

Source: [Android Studio: "Waiting for device." Trying to run app on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028668/android-studio-waiting-for-device-trying-to-run-app-on-phone)