# Android Studio - stuck at waiting for device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have Samsung galaxy S3 (Android version 5.1 , lollipop) , and I'm trying to run my app from the android studio program directly , when I run the app it got stuck on waiting for device .

Example :

```
Waiting for device. Target device: samsung-gt_i9300-4df1db2279965f65 

Uploading file local path: C:\Users\AmirMat\AndroidStudioProjects\Chat\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk  

remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.chat.amirmat.chat
```

It looks like that its trying to upload the file to the device but noth is happening .

The Android debugging mode is on , (adb is on).
ADB over network also on .

I have tried to re-plug the device , and remains same problem .
At the logcat I can see that the device is defined .

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: cmd>adb kill-server after cmd>adb start-server apply this command for restarting adb

Comment: Solved it after switching to another USB cable

Answer (score 0):

put your android device to (media device) mtp  then disconnect and plug in again

Answer (score -1):

**Method**

- open command line where adb is located
- Type `adb kill-server`
- remove the `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub`
- remove the device
- Replug again or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18011126/5019937) before repluging
- open command line again
- Type `adb start-server` or `adb devices`
- check again

Comment: This does not work , when typing adb devices , my device is listed :
List of devices attached
4df1db2279965f65        device

but still it remains stuck at the waiting for device .
I have tried this procedure before


I get new message after trying this method : 

PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 4df1db2279965f65: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.

Comment: Did you removed the adbkey?

Comment: I have not voted for it :) yet ..

By the way I think its a problem with my devices version , I have tried my friend device and it worked .

Comment: I think you didn't accept the RSS prompt or no checked always allow

Comment: I have resolved the problem , the solution was only to use another USB cable . I have noticed that when I tried to copy a random file into my phone , it got stuck during the copying also , so after I have changed the cable the problem solved .

Thank you so much for trying to help me , I appreciate that :)